# Word-request Stuck over something

Tags: word-request

I'm looking for a word that means: *stuck over one thing*.

**Context:** *I'm doing (repeating,using) one thing over and over again.*

**Examples:** *Every time when I create my music I use the same FX chains on every piece.*
*Every morning when I come to work I recompile my software with a current day timestamp.*

Either one word or an idiom would be acceptable. Yet, I prefer one word.

Comment: You are [*in a rut*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/be-in-a-rut), perhaps?

Comment: There's not nearly enough detail. Please give a fuller description, and perhaps a sentence where you would use this WORD. Does it have to be a single word, would an idiom also be acceptable?

Comment: BTW, we would normally say *stuck* **on** one thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending in the context, you might say that you are "stuck in a rut". For example:

> David felt like he was **stuck in a rut**, so he went back to school.
>
> Anne was tired of being **in a rut**, so she moved to Los Angeles.

The expression itself alludes to a wagon whose wheels only go straight because of the ruts in the road. Turning the wagon is difficult as is changing one's routine.

[edit]

Your edit to the original post gives a little more scope, as 'stuck in a rut' implies that this is not a situation you want to be in, and would like it to change.

If you are simply describing the process of repeating the same action on a regular basis, the words '*routinely*', '*consistently*' or '*habitually*' come to mind. For example:

> I **routinely** recompile my software with a current day timestamp.
>
> I **habitually** recompile my software with a current day timestamp.
>
> I **consistently** recompile my software with a current day timestamp.

for a situation where you want to imply a negative connotation, words like '*tedium*' or '*monotony*' can be used to describe a situation where you are tired of doing the same thing over and over again.

Comment: Interesting idiom... might be my choice... any other possible variants?

Comment: I'm always confusing you with @mick, and yet your avatars are very different. BTW it was mick who first suggested [**in a rut**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/113499/word-request-stuck-over-something#comment228487_113499)

Comment: +1 for the subsequent suggestions which fit better the OP's request. Context (clear explanations) is everything.

Comment: @Mari-LouA What's the problem? I don't have one. You should know my policy by now.

Comment: @Mick what's your problem? I upvoted mike's answer because the second set of suggestions fit better.

Comment: "Stuck in a loop" is another possibility.  A "rut" doesn't always imply the same thing over and over, but more that it's difficult to change course.

Comment: I like *tedium*